# Does anyone know what typeface this geometric, sans-serif font is?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Does anyone know what typeface this is? The bar on the 'G' is quite unique but unfortunately most of the font identification sites can't pick it out. It's the typeface used for the "From Japan" book published by Counter-Print which you can see [here](http://www.thisisgrafisk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cover.jpg).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: How did you get that sample you included in your post? Do you have a hi-resolution scanned version of the book cover? If so, could you post more than just one word? The images you can find online are so small it’s hard to make out details.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the typeface Fugue.

http://www.radimpesko.com/fonts/fugue

[image]

Comment: When suggesting fonts please make sure to include a screenshot of the font.

Answer (score 1):

This font seems to be an Illustrator retouched "Relish Pro" or "Windlesham Pro" (Red rooster collection)

Identified thanks to What The Font https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

A Comparison between the supplied image and Windlesham Pro Medium

[image: Windlesham Pro medium]

Comment: If it’s either of those two (both of which seem to be the same font?), then it’s certainly ‘retouched’ a hell of a lot. It’s _very_ different to Relish/Windlesham.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)